# Get the information in iOS/Android Firebase about a user click on a Google Ad

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-play, app-store, google-ads-api

My target is to get the information in my app of the origin of the user: does he/she come from a Google Ad click?

The flow is: Google Ad -> AppStore/GooglePlay -> App Download -> App Opening -> Firebase custom event (like Register or whatever).

When we connect Firebase and Google Ad together, we can have the conversion funnel available in Google Ads.

It means that the tracker is available in Firebase within the iOS/Android app.

Is it possible to retrieve this tracker from Firebase?
I want to send this information to Mixpanel that the user downloaded an app thanks to a Google Ad click.

PS: any answer is good, but I will use React Native or Flutter to implement this behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, integrate firebase with the app React Native or Flutter. The next step is to track the custom events if someone registers or downloads the app, the Firebase Analytics API will track custom events that are performed by a customer. Firebase Analytics API will retrieve the custom event from Firebase to get the data whereas an app is downloaded or someone registers then that data will send to Mixpanel. For that purpose, we need Mixpanel API to track events and send data to Mixpanel. This is the whole flow that you have mentioned above.

> The flow is : Google Ad -> AppStore/GooglePlay -> App Download -> App
> Opening -> Firebase custom event (like Register or whatever).

```
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/observer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mixpanel/mixpanel.dart';

void main() => runApp(AnaudambroApp());

class AnaudambroApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<AnaudambroApp> {
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  Mixpanel mixpanel = Mixpanel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    analytics.logEvent(name: 'App Download', parameters: {'source': 'Google Ad'});
    mixpanel.track('App Download', {'source': 'Google Ad'});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [
        FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
      ],
      // add your code here
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but how do you know `'source': 'Google Ad'` ?

Comment: I mean that's the whole point of my question: how do I know the source is Google Ad ?

Comment: Set up Firebase and Google ad integration so that the conversion data is tracked in firebase. It will be your Google ad source. Access the conversion data using Firebase Analytics API from your app @arnaudambro

Comment: Once you have conversion data send it to Mixpanel via their Tracking API. @arnaudambro

Comment: > Access the conversion data using Firebase Analytics API from your app : yes that's what I'm looking for! but that's not what you're showing, are you?

Comment: Add your app to the Firebase Project from Firebase Console after creating the project in Firebase. Enable the Firebase Analytics and set up the conversion tracking events that you want to track like registering or downloading your app. Access that conversion data  that you have collected from Firebase analytics API. @arnaudambro

Comment: mmm would you have a link of Google documentation or anything showing me how to get this Firebase analytics API? I can't find it - lost in google's documentation

Comment: Check out google documentation for set up events and conversion  for reference https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article @arnaudambro

Comment: create Google Ads with Google Analytics for Firebase custom events - Android for reference https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase_android_ads#0

Comment: As you have mentioned above you have conversion funnel available I wonder still your struggling

Comment: I've done all of this, but you talk about access the conversion data using Firebase Analytics API from your app : how ? where ?

Comment: I have mentioned all the steps with official documentation @arnaudambro

Comment: maybe I'm blind! but you're talking about Firebase Analytics API and I see nowhere in your docs this service - and I still have no clue to have access to Firebase Analytics API from the app

Comment: check out this article everything is  mentioned with screen shots https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase_android_ads#4  1.Create a Firebase project.   2 Sign in to Firebase.  3.Add Firebase to your Android app 4.Add Firebase SDK to your app 5.Log events with Firebase Analytics 6.Import Firebase events into Google Ads 7.Launching app action campaigns with imported events

Comment: Yes user reaction will tell from where user comes from and which device he is using